# Understanding japanese verb suffixes

Tags: etymology, conjugations, suffixes, classical-japanese

I recently learned the meaning of the verb suffixes す, む and ぶ (respectively to do, to seem like or to indicate volition, to act like).

I would have two questions :

Does every verb ending with す can be linked with the doing, the making of an action ? (same question, respectively, for verbs ending in む and ぶ)

What about the meaning of verb suffixes る, う, つ, く and ぐ ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Never come across this concept before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible that there is some artifact truth in what you found:  particularly in classical Japanese.  But for the modern language, I find it a stretch to think that verbs as diverse as こむ, よむ, たのむ, or すむ have much of a connection to *volition* in terms of their meaning or that verbs such as とぶ, よぶ, or むすぶ have much to do with *acting like*.  Etymologically it might be possible, but not in a way that modern speakers would be much conscious of, if at all.

Comment: For ぶ :  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%B3%E3%82%8B#Japanese  ;  for す and む :https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86494/why-are-there-so-many-three-kana-kunyomi-verbs-beginning-with-%E3%81%82 (see the answer)

Comment: Yes, for me too, it was quite strange that one meaning can incorporate such diverse verbs, but it was implied in the answer of the second link I provided

Comment: Your 2nd link is more about classical Japanese and perhaps etymological origins, but it's not really saying anything about the *productivity* of these endings in the modern language.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. Perhaps what confused me further was this Wiktionary article, that clearly addresses む as a verb suffix https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AF%E3%82%89%E3%82%80